# Can Windows 2008 R2 DNS set TTL per record?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ttl

The DNS Manager administrative tool doesn't seem to have an option for configuring TTL for an individual record. I can set the TTL per-zone by right-clicking -> Properties -> SOA. Where is the equivalent for each record?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In DNS manager, click view-->advanced.

Then open a DNS record.  There will be some new fields, including TTL.

Works on server 2008 and 2003.

Comment: This applies to Windows 2012 R2 as well